# Ubuntu 17.04 package system is broken

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, python3

After upgrading from 16.10 to 17.04, I'm getting a popup from the 
"Check if you are using third party repositories. If so disable them, since they are a common source of problems.
Furthermore run the following command in a Terminal: apt-get install -f"

Attempting that and other solutions about the package system, I'm still stuck with:

```
> sudo apt --fix-broken install ... Setting up python3.5-minimal
> (3.5.3-1) ... 
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/usr/lib/python3.5/py_compile.py", line 6, in <module>
>     import importlib._bootstrap_external   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
>     import types   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/types.py", line 166, in <module>
>     import functools as _functools   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/functools.py", line 23, in <module>
>     from weakref import WeakKeyDictionary   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/weakref.py", line 12, in <module>
>     from _weakref import ( ImportError: cannot import name '_remove_dead_weakref' dpkg: error processing package
> python3.5-minimal (--configure):  subprocess installed
> post-installation script returned error exit status 1 dpkg: dependency
> problems prevent configuration of python3-minimal:  python3-minimal
> depends on python3.5-minimal (>= 3.5.3-1~); however:   Package
> python3.5-minimal is not configured yet.
> 
> dpkg: error processing package python3-minimal (--configure): 
> dependency problems - leaving unconfigured No apport report written
> because the error message indicates its a followup error from a
> previous failure.
>                           Errors were encountered while processing:  python3.5-minimal  python3-minimal E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg
> returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: The instructions in this link worked for me.
https://superuser.com/questions/1200416/failed-to-upgrade-from-16-10-to-17-04-now-apt-throws-errors

Comment: Finally got those instructions to work.  Went through several other articles, that may have fixed something else... Thanks